# Why will the css in my django project not render?

Tags: python, css, django

I'm still just playing around with Django and cannot figure out what I am doing wrong with my CSS file.  My HTML works but not the CSS.  I'm guessing it has something to do with settings.py or some special "Django code" I'm not using.  Here is the code for my HTML (what I am guessing is the relevant code to show).

Here is my HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>home</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../css/styles.css"/>
  </head>
  <body>

    <h3>HELLO WORLD!</h3>

  </body>
</html>
```

Here is my settings.py:

```
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'ecommerce005.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
    }
}
```

Here is my urls.py:

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from django.contrib import admin

from .views import home_page

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', home_page),
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
]
```

Here is my views.py:

```
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.shortcuts import render

def home_page(request):
    return render(request, "index.html", {})
```

The order of my file are as follows:
'src' directory:
    1) 'css' folder holds my styles.css file
    2) 'projectname' folder contains all of my django files shown above
    3) 'templates' folder holds my index.html file

Please be as specific as possible.  I found sources online but they seemed too vague for me to find a solution.  I appreciate your help.

Comment: Did you enabled `staticfiles`? Perhaps it is better to write the file *tree*.

Comment: As it's missing some information in your code how you handle static files, please take a look on the [Django Tutorial](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/intro/tutorial06/) for static files and CSS

Answer (score 1):

Configure static files in **settings.py**

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS=[
    (os.path.dirname(BASE_DIR),"static"),
]
STATIC_ROOT = (os.path.dirname(BASE_DIR),"static_files")
```

In Templates,(ie HTML file)

```
{% load static %}
<html>
 ....
<link href="{% static 'styles/style.css' %}" rel="stylesheet" media="screen, print" type="text/css">
```

**Directory Structure**
-ProjectFolder

--|static

----|styles

------|styles.css

Answer (score 0):

You need to setup a 'STATIC_ROOT' in the settings.py

```
STATIC_URL = '/staticfiles/'
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, '/static/')
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static"),
]
```

If DEBUG=False, you need to setup your proxy server such as nginx to serve these staticfiles

This [link](https://help.pythonanywhere.com/pages/DjangoStaticFiles/) can explain it further.

Answer (score 0):

Wootton, as was said, you need to setup your static_root on settings.py, after that you can just call your css

```
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="{{ STATIC_URL }}css/style-responsive.css">
```

but before/after setup the static_root you need to create a folder named static and serve your css in there.

I think this will help you!